# What is a pyomo set, nowhere in the documentation is it properly defined

Tags: set, pyomo

"Sets can be declared using instances of the Set and RangeSet classes or by assigning set expressions. The simplest set declaration creates a set and postpones creation of its members."

That isn't a definition, what should a set be used for?

Comment: There is an example of Pyomo Set variables in [github](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/examples/pyomo/tutorials/set.py).

Comment: Also not a definition of what a Set is

Answer (score 4):

A set is an indexing mechanism.  If you are familiar with basic python, you index lists by a numerical index.  You can “index” a dictionary by keys that are hashable, etc.

So in most models you have collections of things, perhaps products, with variables and parameters (constants) that are related to these collections.  So you might have a group of products `{pc, tablet, iphone}` and parameters that are logically indexed by this set…. `cost[pc], cost[tablet]`, etc.

In Pyomo, you can declare a set and use that set to index a variable or parameter, etc.  At the simplest level, you can just use a range of numbers, but you might use something more logical, depending on the model.

If this is confusing, you might consider locating an introductory textbook on Linear Programming.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pyomo Documentation Release 6.4.2](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyomo/downloads/pdf/stable/) defines `Set` as *A component used to index other components*. (cf page 255)

Pyomo Set objects are compatible with Python set objects. It might help to look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):
*A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements*.

Sets can be used to model the presence or absence of properties (colors, brands, etc). Sets are basic data structures for all sorts of algorithms. They can be used to model the relations between other objects. The theory of sets was historically promoted/discussed as the basis of mathematics ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki)).